# How to prove time complexity of bubble sort using dafny?

Tags: time-complexity, bubble-sort, proof, dafny

Is there a way in dafny to create an invariant specific to a single loop iteration? Below I'm trying to create a dafny program to upper bound the number of swaps of bubble sort. That value is stored in variable n. So I'd like to upper bound n by (a.Length * (a.Length - 1))/2. The reason being is that the maximum number of swaps that can occur is if the array is in the opposite order so then there must be n swaps on the first iteration of the inside loop and then n-1 swaps of the second iteration of the inside loop, etc. until the array is sorted. This is equivalent to 1+2+3+...+n-1+n = n(n-1)/2, which is precisely what I'm trying to show. I'm wondering if there's a method in dafny to upper bound the value of i-j or n in the code below based on the iteration of the inner loop. Is there such a way?

If not is there another method to upper bound this n value given the explanation provided above? Perhaps additional invariants I'm not thinking of?

```
method BubbleSort(a: array<int>) returns (n: nat) 
      modifies a
      requires a != null
      ensures n <= (a.Length * (a.Length - 1))/2
    {
        var i := a.Length - 1;
        n := 0;
        while (i > 0)
          invariant 0 < a.Length ==> 0 <= i < a.Length;
          decreases i;
           {
            var j := 0;
            while (j < i)
            invariant i - j <= old(i) - old(j);
            invariant i < 0 && j < 0 ==> 0 <= n <= a.Length;
            decreases i - j;
              {
                if(a[j] > a[j+1])
                  {
                    a[j], a[j+1] := a[j+1], a[j];
                    n := n + 1;
                  }
                  j := j + 1;
              }
              i := i -1;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to "create an invariant specific to a single loop iteration", but instead to rephrase your loop invariants in a way that they apply to all iterations.

Your English argument for why the complexity is bounded is a good one.

> the maximum number of swaps that can occur is if [there are] n swaps on the first iteration of the inside loop and then n-1 swaps of the second iteration of the inside loop, etc. until the array is sorted. This is equivalent to 1+2+3+...+n-1+n = n(n-1)/2

All you need to do is to formalize this argument into Dafny. I suggest introducing a function for "the sum of all integers between `a` and `b`" and then using that function to phrase your loop invariants.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer. When I put this into Dafny I get an error at the calc block. Namely, SumRange(1, a.Length) <= NChoose2(a.Length). I've simplified the code that's written but the error message is "the calculation step between the previous line and this line might not hold". Why might this be and how could I resolve that?

Comment: it's hard to say. you said you put exactly the code in my answer into dafny and it failed? what version of dafny are you using, and what version of z3?

Comment: It's the same exact code. I'm using version 3.2.0.30713. Should I be using a different version?

Comment: I've tried re-working the argument and posted a new comment with my refactored code. I'm trying to say something is true by the n choose 2 lemma and now I'm getting an error there. If you have a moment can you please see what I'm doing wrong with that where I invoke a lemma as justficaton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427363/how-to-invoke-lemma-in-dafny-in-bubblesort-example

Comment: I have double checked and my code checks with dafny version `3.2.0.30713` and the default z3 version of `4.8.5`. Can you post exactly the code and exactly how you are checking it with dafny and exactly the error message you get? I also responded to your other question.

Comment: I completely uninstalled dafny and then reinstalled and then it worked just fine. Thanks very much, James!